# Node/Express/Jade seems to be canceling resource requests intermittently

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm starting up on a new project here at work that uses node.js with express and jade. We're converting an existing dashboard site into a one-page webapp, and I'm in the process of setting everything up on my local machine and getting it running. At the moment, I've got it working to where it'll render the jade (which we generated) files and serve them.

Unfortunately it only works about 80-90% of the time. The other times random resources will fail to load because (according to Chrome) they were 'canceled'.

[image: Canceled resources]

The resources that are canceled seem to be random. Sometimes it's one CSS file, sometimes it's just jQuery, sometimes it's a few, sometimes it's almost all, sometimes it's images, etc. AFAIK, the only way to cancel a resource request is to hit the stop button or call `window.stop`, neither of which is happening any place I can find.

My initial thought was that for some reason resources were taking too long to load, so I added a:

```
img(src="http://deelay.me/5000/http://deelay.me/img/5000ms.gif")
```

to my index.jade file, but interestingly enough, that seems to cause everything to load perfectly fine. Even with a delay of only 500ms, everything appears to work. Dropping it down to 100ms and I'll start seeing canceled resources again.

I've added error handling to my app.js, and don't appear to be getting any errors. Anybody have any ideas or things I could try? Apologies for the vague title and tags, but I can't tell exactly what part is failing.

Comment: I haven't got an answer but it sound interesting enough to help out finding the root cause. Does this happen only in Chrome or other browsers as well?

Comment: I got busy on other projects and hadn't checked it in other browsers until just now. Reloaded the page about 40x in Firefox and everything loaded fine. Tried it again in Chrome another 40x... and everything loaded fine. I had commented out that deelay.me image and literally nothing else has changed. I'm completely stumped at this point.